# How thick are the intergalactic filaments?

Tags: observational-astronomy, astrophysics, intergalactic-space

Recently, in October, news came out about the faint intergalactic filaments finally being 'found'.

Then, in June, astronomers announced that these things had enough normal matter in them to solve the 'missing baryon problem'.

Although their length(s) are often mentioned, nowhere do I hear about their width/thickness....

These 'Warm-hot intergalactic filaments' are described as long, thin filaments of plasma;  brought together by gravity....

Does anybody have an idea as to these filaments' thickness/width?

Comment: intergalactic filaments of one type or another are also mentioned in these somewhat related questions [How is it determined that the X-ray and radio intensity come from a magnetic field bridge between two clusters of galaxies?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32199/7982) and [Why is the Warm-Hot Intergalactic Medium (WHIM) so hot, and what is “collisionless shock heating”?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26707/7982) and [What exactly are infrared dark clouds and what is the significance of the orientation of their magnetic fields?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34067/7982)

Comment: and [Why did it take five years to “figure out” how to use astrometric calibration sources to deblur LOFAR images?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36862/7982).